# Getting “Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND” when trying to load a background image in httpdocs, load in localhost is OK

Tags: html, css

I got some problems now. My code 
`background-image: url(/assets/img/2.company/banner02.jpg);`
is work in `localhost:3000/` but when I open file `.html` in folder `httpdocs`, it giving `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. please help me.

Comment: Can you share the url? What is the address of the file shown in the error message?

Comment: file:///assets/img/1.index/cont01-1.png 
this is the address and my url is 
file:///C:/Task03/template/httpdocs/assets/img/1.index/cont01-1.jpg

Comment: You can edit your question to include a pic but you can't post them in the comments.

Comment: I've fixed it. Thanks for your help.